# Hook APIs that imported to program by LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook

I know how I can hook functions from the IAT table, but I have a problem with APIs which were imported by calling **`LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress`** functions. I want to know exactly how someone could hook those functions. I realize that I should hook the **`GetProcAddress`** function but how can I check the parameters that were passsed to that function?

For example, consider a program which is going to include `MessageBoxW` via **`LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress`**, how can I hook that `MessageBoxW` and then check the parameters that have been passed to it?

I have searched a lot in StackOverflow and Google, but I couldn't find a step-by-step tutorial about this. So, if you have such a tutorial or article, I would be really grateful to read them.

Comment: You could hook GetProcAddress. You could also hook the actual MessageBoxW function in the DLL.

Comment: is there any example for this getprocaddress hook?

Comment: If you know how to hook IAT entries, what's the specific challenge in hooking the particular `GetProcAddress` import? This question reads a lot like *"I don't know what I'm doing. Give me the codez, plz. Kthnx"*. That's not what a Q&A site is for. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: No, please read my question carefully. I know exactly how hook function from IAT. I know how can I hook getprocaddress too. but my challenges when I wanted to parse parameters which passed to the imported function with getproc/loadlibrary pair. maybe i am a little confused with this approaches so if you give me some hint i will implemented by myself.

Comment: Since when you load a library by calling `LoadLibrary`, the library will mapped into the address space of the target process, you can use IAT hook again for `MessageBoxW` in your example. There is no difference.

Comment: @RolfRollesKing hooking a function imported by `GetProcAddress()` is no different than hooking a function imported by IAT. They both require you to have a pointer to the target function, which you then use to inject a jump in the original function to another function. Your injected function then has access to the original parameters. When hooking `GetProcAddress()`, your hook has access to its parameters and the pointer it returns. If you don't understand that, then you don't understand hooks at all, IAT or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to hook APIs that they are loaded into a binary dynamically with help of LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress, you should intercept return address of the GetProcAddress and name of the functions that passed to it (for example, consider a program try to load MessageBoxA in this way).

In the second step, you should save that original address of MessageBoxA API in a variable like OriginalMessageBoxA.

In the third and final step, you should return address of your modified API (HookedMessageBoxA) to the callee of the GetProcAddress so when the program try to call that address, program redirected to your function. Something like the following one:

```
VOID* HookedGetProcAddress(HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName)
{
    if (std::string(lpProcName).compare("MessageBoxA") == 0)
    {
        OMessageBoxA = (PMessageBoxA)GetProcAddress(hModule, lpProcName);
        return HookedMessageBoxA;
    }
    else
    {
        return OGetProcAddress(hModule, lpProcName);
    }
}
```

In that moment, caller will go through your HookedMessageBoxA and you can check parameters that passed to MessageBoxA. As folks said, it is kinda same like normal IAT hook with a minor changes and tricks.